# ASP.NET MVC RC Form Parameters Problem

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC Beta I was able to get the form parameters of

```
<input id="addresses[40].City" name="addresses[40].City" type="text" value="City" />
<input id="addresses[40].Country" name="addresses[40].Country" type="text" value="Country" />
```

as `Edit(List<Address> addresses)` in controller action.

Nonetheless, in the new Release Candidate I cannot retrieve the values(null) as a parameter in action. I can see the values when I make a FormCollection parameter, but it will be a headache to parse all the Key/Value pairs into a object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The scheme for list binding changed in the release candidate. Prior to the release candidate, you would have a hidden field which indicated what the index was (40, in your case). In the release candidate, you no longer need this hidden field, but your index **must be numeric and must start with 0.**

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Shame this wasn't in the Release Notes!

Comment: Agree on that, although this caused me a lot of headache, it solved the problem.